# How to build an iOS Unity Project for iOS Device as well as iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, ios-simulator

Currently i have a unity project which runs on iOS device or iOS simulator.
I have choose SDK choice in unity project player settings ,option available for choose either device sdk or simulator sdk.. i just want to build a single unity project for running iOS Devices and simulators,Can any one give me suggestions to achieve this..

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible because Apple not supports universal builds with both device and simulator binaries. Unity just generates XCode project for you. And you can choose the target SDK (Device or Simulator) in XCode directly after the project was generated. So this is not a Unity limitation.

If you build for Simulator you compile for x86 architecture. But when you build for Device you compile for arm7. arm7 binary cannot run on x86 Simulator.

Comment: but how do you build for simulator?